# How to convert V-Ray materials to Arnold-compatible materials

Tags: python, maya

How to convert V-Ray materials to Arnold-compatible materials. I'm new in Maya, so if you have any ideas please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`V-Ray` and `Arnold` are fundamentally different renders. Due to their specific math for shading, this is absolutely impossible.

Even if you find a way to do this conversion, the materials will not work as they did before – that's because `V-Ray` uses Deterministic Monte Carlo (DMC) sampling algorithm, whilst `Arnold` uses Advanced Monte Carlo ray tracing method.